# Pandas DataFrame TypeError: quantile() missing 1 required positional argument: 'quantile'?

Tags: python, pandas

data

```
data = [
    {"content": "1", "title": "app sotre", "info": "", "time": 1578877014},
    {"content": "2", "title": "app", "info": "", "time": 1579877014},
    {"content": "3", "title": "pandas", "info": "", "time": 1582877014},
    {"content": "12", "title": "a", "info": "", "time": 1582876014},
    {"content": "33", "title": "apple", "info": "", "time": 1581877014},
    {"content": "16", "title": "banana", "info": "", "time": 1561877014},
    {"content": "aa", "title": "banana", "info": "", "time": 1582876014},
]
```

my code

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['content'] = pd.to_numeric(df['content'], errors='coerce')
print('-----')
print(df['content'].rolling(2).quantile())
```

raise error :TypeError: quantile() missing 1 required positional argument: 'quantile'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think problem is no default `quantile` in [`Rolling.quantile`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.quantile.html):

```
print(df['content'].rolling(2).quantile(0.5))
```

But if check all another methods there is always default quantile:

[`Series.quantile`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.quantile.html), [`DataFrame.quantile`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.quantile.html), [`DataFrameGroupBy.quantile`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.quantile.html), [`Resampler.quantile`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.quantile.html).

Comment: but quantile is default q=0.5

Comment: @xin.chen - added link to answer